# Count of slaps (combinatorics or dp)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math

Ömer is one of the beloved people. Everybody loves him and he loves his friends too. He doesn’t have any bad habits in his life except one. He really likes to slap his friends whenever he thinks it is necessary. Nobody has a problem with that because they know Ömer slaps his friends to make them better just like himself.
On a casual day at inzva’s great hall, Ömer lined up his friends and began slapping them one by one. At that time, Havva ( the one Ömer fears the most ) came to the hall and saw the slapping process. She immediately set some rules for Ömer’s bad habit before it was too late.

•Ömer will line up his n friends in a row. Beginning from one end of the line, he can slap a person or not. Then he will move on to the next person on the line.

•He can not slap two adjacent people on that line. (to avoid overslapping)

•He can not pass more than 2 people without slapping any of them.

Ömer wasn’t happy with these regulations but he still followed the rules. But he wants to know how many different patterns of slapping he can create with his n friends. Can you help Ömer to find this number?
The answer can be too large, so print it in modulo 1e3+7.
It is important that the result must not exceed the integer limit while processing at any step.
İnput-->Output
465-->672
4-->5
1-->2

I want to get formula with combinatorics.How I do this?

Comment: Got a laugh out of this one

Comment: What have you tried?  How are you approaching the problem? What techniques do you think is involved?

Comment: I would look into Graph coloring for this. You can model the line of people as a line graph of vertices. Then your question can be phrased as "How many ways are there to color a line graph with n vertices with two colors with some stipulation." I'll leave it to you to think about how to specify the stipulations.

Comment: In line with @Pita's comment, was just wondering "How many binary strings have no consecutive 1s *and* no more than 2 consecutive 0s?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $S$ a slap, and $P$ a pass.

The number of strings of length $(n)$ from an alphabet $\{S,P\}$ with no more than one $S$ and no more than two $P$'s consecutively, is given by the famous [Padovan sequence](https://oeis.org/A000931) when offset 8. That is, start the Padovan sequence for $a_n$ with an offset 8 to obtain Ömer's pattern count $ö_n=a_{n+8}$.

The first few numbers of compositions are

$\ a_9=ö_1=2 \rightarrow [P,S]$
$a_{10}=ö_2=3 \rightarrow [PP,PS,SP]$
$a_{11}=ö_3=4 \rightarrow [PPS,PSP,SPP,SPS]$
$a_{12}=ö_4=5 \rightarrow [PPSP,PSPP,PSPS,SPPS,SPSP]$

The recursive formula for the Padovan sequence, with $a_{0}= 1$ and $a_{1}=a_{2}=0$, is $$a_n = a_{n-2} + a_{n-3}$$

A combinatorial formula can be
$$ö_{n-10}=a_{n-2}=\sum _{i=\lceil n/3\rceil }^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor }{i \choose n-2i}$$

Since you are expected to give the answer modulo $1007$, an explicit formula for your problem can be

$$\color{red}{ö_{n-10}=\sum _{i=\lceil n/3\rceil }^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}{i\choose n-2i} \mod 1007}$$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But the Padowan sequence doesn't seem to solve the given examples. Please let me know if I'm wrong. I placed the examples in the question. ö(465)=672

Comment: ö(n)=ans,ö(465)=672,   ö(4)=5, ö(1)=2, these were gave in the question, I corrected them.

Comment: thank you very much